# Windows 10 Creators Update changes the style of PropertyGrid control

Tags: windows, winforms, propertygrid

I just upgraded some systems to Windows 10 Creators Update and I noticed that the windows forms `PropertyGrid` control changed its default visual style for headers and bar margins to dark gray, like so:

[image: <code>PropertyGrid</code> new style]

And as mostly happens with unexpected visual changes, users are not happy. Is there a way to revert back to the old default or maybe override the default style?

Comment: It is the same color as PropertyGrid.LineColor.  Given that it changed, you probably left it at its default setting, SystemColors.InactiveBorder.  Microsoft does tinker with the system colors to make new versions of Windows look different.  Or you selected the color scheme you preferred, hard to guess.  Changing system colors has gotten a lot more difficult in later versions, [this superuser.com question](https://superuser.com/questions/949920/window-color-and-appearance-removed-in-win10) has details.  The registry hack is the only useful one I imagine.

Comment: On serveral machines here in my company, this is indeed caused by a Microsoft update. Tools running for several months now has a different style. Is there any place where one can finds changes done by updates?

Comment: @joe: For .NET, they have release notes [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/tree/master/releases), including links to known issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a bug in PropertyGrid:

The property [`PropertyGrid.LineColor`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGrid.cs,d1af75212eec49f8) has a `DefaultValue` attribute Set to `SystemColors.InactiveBorder`.
But the internal field [`lineColor`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGrid.cs,e25c036be7f82ec5) is initialized with `SystemColors.ControlDark`.

This is bad, because the Windows Forms designer detects that the property has the same value as the `DefaultValue` attribute, and therefore it does not write the designer code for the `PropertyGrid.LineColor` property in `InitializeComponent`. So at runtime, the property is initialized to `SystemColors.ControlDark`.

As a quick hack, you can set the property after `InitializeComponent`:

```
InitializeComponent();
propertyGrid.LineColor = SystemColors.InactiveBorder;
```

Comment: And as always, the `System.Windows.Forms` version deployed on the developer's computer specifies `SystemColors.InactiveBorder` for the `lineColor` field.

Comment: You can vote for this through Visual Studio's "Report a Problem", typing `The LineColor of PropertyGrid is defined inconsistent`. The existing problem report indicates that the change was introduced with .NET 4.7.

Comment: @tm1: Thanks, didn't know that you can report a bug directly through Visual Studio, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We are reverting header color to InactiveBorder in the default windows theme in the next release of the .Net Framework, which most likely will be included in the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update. The reason this change was introduced, was that the foreground and background colors were not contrasting enough in one of the High Contrast themes, this is why we are reverting to the previously used color only in the default theme.
For your reference, internal work item number, that will be also mentioned in release notes for .Net Framework 4.7.1, is 407249.

Thank you, Tanya

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a "feature". From the [.NET Framework 4.7 Release Notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net47/dotnet47-changes.md#windows-forms):

> Changed the background color of property grid lines to provide an 8:1 contrast ratio for high contrast themes.

So, I'd say, no, with Windows 10 Creators Update, there's no way to revert to the old style without recompiling (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44802829/806690) answer).

I complained [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/393#issuecomment-312631247).

**Update**

I refined the `PropertyGrid` class like this:

```
sealed class LightPropertyGrid : PropertyGrid {
    static readonly Color DefaultLineColor = (Color)
        typeof(PropertyGrid)
            .GetProperty(nameof(LineColor))
            .GetCustomAttribute<DefaultValueAttribute>()
            .Value;

    public LightPropertyGrid() {
        LineColor = DefaultLineColor;
    }
}
```

I'm inferring the initial value for `LineColor` from the default value defined on the same property. Of course, you can simply assign `LineColor = SystemColors.InactiveBorder`.