# DefaultPropertyAttribute in Propertygrid control showing the background color as gray after load

Tags: c#, .net

Background color for a DefaultPropertyattribute shown as gray after loading form as shown in below image.

[image: SaveOnClose]

how to remove that color while loading the form.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: This solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43609548/1379418