# PropertyGrid look-and-feel appearance changed

Tags: winforms, propertygrid, look-and-feel

Something changed the look-and-feel of the Windows.Forms PropertyGrid:

[image: PropertyGrids within my applications form look different/darker now (compare to Properties control in lower right)]

It looks darker, uglier, and more importantly, breaks visual appearance with all other GUI elements. Other GUI controls remain as they were (as far as I can tell).
Of course, `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` and `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);` are set the way the wizard set them up.

I am not sure what caused this, but it affects all my CSharp projects in MSVS 2015 and MSVS 2017.

Older projects that I didn't compile in ages seem not to be affected. There the PropertyGrid looks fine.

In newer projects I tried switching down to other .Net version, down to 2.0. No changes; PropertyGrid stays dark and ugly.

I installed and uninstalled many things before I noticed that change. Among others some updates to Visual Studio, QT incl. Creator and VS Addin, MSVS 2013, MSVS 2012, ... Too many to try uninstalling them all.

Any ideas what could have caused this, and how to get rid of this change?

Comment: Is this only in the IDE or at compiled app runtime?

Comment: Both IDE and (newly) compiled app at runtime.

Comment: Actually I think I have the same look, not sure if it's good or bad :-/ I don't have an old propertygrid app around to test...

Comment: Interestingly, there is s difference between `LineColor` property `DefaultValue` and the [backing field initializer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGrid.cs,92). I don't know why is that, but it's causing generation of additional line in the designer cs. To get the old look and feel, select the `LineColor` property and invoke *Reset* command.

Comment: Actually Reset doesn't work. And no way to set that in designer because setting it to `InactiveBorder` will not be preserved, and the next time you open it in design/runtime, it gets the `ControlDark` :(

Comment: I can run "old" apps and "newly compiled" apps at the same time. One looks as it should, the other one is dark. At least I am somewhat soothed I am not the only one with this problem. (I didn't find anything via google, and started to wonder...) It's not only `LineColor` The toggle tick button thingies are +-boxes in 'good' and arrow heads in 'bad'.

Comment: AH! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609548/windows-10-creators-update-changes-the-style-of-propertygrid-control